# ODBC Connection to a postgress database is not working from RStudio

Tags: r, odbc, rstudio, rodbc

```
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
Driver = "Denodo",
Server = "denodous-db.com",
Database = "dev-db",
UID = "mk12345",
PWD = "Welcome")

table_list <- dbListTables(con)
print(table_list)
```

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1135: 00000: [unixODBC]Could not send Query(connection dead)
```

This is the error message I'm getting while running the code in RStudio. iSQL Connection to the database is successful from the Linux machine.

I'm able to run the same R code above successfully from the Terminal option of Rstudio. It's not working only from the UI.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?